# React shouldComponentUpdate detect change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I must be doing something dumb here, but after a day of trying to figure it out, I am turning here...

I have a dropdown menu for each element of an array `val` which I save in the Component state:

```
class C extends Component {

    state = { val : [ 1,2,3,4] }
    ...

}
```

where a change in each of the dropdown entries triggers this callback:

```
  onChanged = (event, index) => {
    console.log("val changed");
    this.setState(state => {
      const val = state.val;
      val[index] = event.target.value;
      return { val: val };
    });
  };
```

Now the issue is that I can't figure out how to detect this change in `shouldComponentUpdate`. Specifically, when I change one of the dropdown options, I see `val changed` being logged. However, in the `shouldComponentUpdate` method, the `nextState` and `this.state` always contain the same values (and appear to be identical on comparison). So there is no way for me to detect a change in `shouldComponentUpdate`. Here is the exact code I am using:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    console.log(
      "shouldComponentUpdate",
      nextProps.val,
      this.state.val,
      nextState.val,
      this.state.val === nextState.val
    );
    return false;
}
```

Before a change in one of the dropdown options, this logs something like

```
shouldComponentUpdate, undefined, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], true
```

If I change the first dropdown from `1` to `9`, then I see

```
shouldComponentUpdate, undefined, [9, 2, 3, 4], [9, 2, 3, 4], true
```

I expected that immediately after the change I would see

```
shouldComponentUpdate, undefined, [1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 2, 3, 4], true
```

Please tell me how I can detect a change in `shouldComponentUpdate` or what idiom I should be using.

EDIT:

It was suggested that I `slice` the value array in the `onChanged` callback, that is, change to callback to:

```
  onChanged = (event, index) => {
    console.log("val changed");
    this.setState(state => {
      const val = state.val.slice();
      val[index] = event.target.value;
      return { val: val };
    });
  };
```

That did not fix the issue. Here is the console log before and after a change:

```
shouldComponentUpdate undefined (4) [1, 2, 3, 4] (4) [1, 2, 3, 4] true
val changed
shouldComponentUpdate undefined (4) [9, 2, 3, 4] (4) [9, 2, 3, 4] true
```

EDIT:

Crikeys I am dumb. There was a dumb return statement that was getting hit. I totally missed it. I am accepting the answer below since they are correct as the problem was stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are mutating the array and re use it.

Change `const val = state.val;` to either

```
const val = [...state.val];
```

or

```
const val = state.val.slice();
```

to create a new array

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried slicing already and that wasn't working. Let me check again

Answer (score 0):

JS arrays are passed by reference and not pass by value.

when you are doing `const val = state.val;` and `val[index] = event.target.value;` it is changing the state variable before setState.

example:

```
var a = {x: [1,2,3]}
var b = a.x
b[0] = 5 // b = [5, 2, 3] and a = {x: [5,2,3]}
```

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to solve your problem.

```
//Slice
const val = state.val.slice()
//Destructure
const val = [...state.val]
```

In the above example:

```
var a = {x: [1,2,3]}
var b = [...a.x]
var c = a.x.slice()
b[0] = 5     //b = [5, 2, 3] and a = {x: [1,2,3]}
c[0] = 6    //b = [6, 2, 3] and a = {x: [1,2,3]}
```